# Regarding Packaging of DApp

Tags: dapp-development, dapps

By now I have tried developing a few contracts, deploying them to a test network and using a Javascript based web application to connect to the contracts and use them.

What I want to understand what is the way to package/bundle the Web app as a DApp and deploy in the block chain. Want to understand how that is different to the traditional way of deploying a centralized web application.

Comment: A reference: [Ethereum Smart Contract Packaging Specification](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/190)

Comment: So does that mean the development for packaging by various framework teams are currently in progress and don't have any version yet available.